# Check for empty value in Array

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

How do I check for empty values in an hashtable, and list the item name as well ?

I could do `if ($Vars.ContainsValue($null))` but this does not get me what item that has a `$null` value

```
    $Vars = @{

    1     = "CustomerID";
    2     = "DepartmentID";
    3     = "Environment";
    4     = "JoinDomain";
    5     = ""

}
```

if I do a `foreach ($var in $vars)` I get the whole hashtable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this is not an `array`, because those are written as `@('element1', 'element2')`. This concerns a `HashTable` which is indicated as `@{}` and is `enumerated` by the `GetEnumerator()` method.

After that method it's simply a matter of filtering out what you need with the `key` and/or the `value` property.

```
$Vars = @{
    1 = "CustomerID";
    2 = "DepartmentID";
    3 = "Environment";
    4 = "JoinDomain";
    5 = ""
}

$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

$Vars.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {
    -not $_.Value
} | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Verbose "The key '$($_.Key)' has no value"
    # Other code for handling the key with no value
}
```

Comment: Nicely done. The following is worth mentioning in general (not a concern with the given data): `-not $_.Value` would also exclude other values, such as `0`, `$false`, or an empty array. Also, arrays are best written as `'element1', 'element2'` - the `@(...)` is not only unnecessary, it is actually less efficient in PowerShell 5.0 and below (though it won't matter in practice). `@(...)` is useful for constructing an empty array or a single-element array, though (the latter can also be constructed as `, <elem>`).